# existence of positive integer and converges to $L$

Tags: real-analysis

if for any given $0 < \epsilon < 1$ there exists a positive integer $N$ so that $|a_n - L| < 5\epsilon$ when $n^2 +1  > N $, then $\{a_n\}$ converges to $L$.

is this true or fase? I do not understand the part  $n^2 + 1 >N$. 
if its true how to make it false statement??

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question to understand the concept of limits in detail below the superficial looks of $\epsilon$'s. You need to understand that the standard definition of limit (convergence of a sequence) involves an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$. Now $5\epsilon $ is as arbitrary and positive as $\epsilon$ is. So we don't have trouble there. Also keeping $0 < \epsilon < 1$ does not matter because for $\epsilon \geq 1$ the inequality holds automatically if it holds for $\epsilon < 1$.

Next we need to figure out what the heck does $n^{2} + 1 > N$ mean. It means $n > \sqrt{N - 1}$ and since $n$ is an integer it means $ n > N_{1}$ where $N_{1} = \lceil \sqrt{N - 1}\rceil$. Hence we see that for any $\epsilon > 0$ we are able to get a positive integer $N_{1}$ such that $|a_{n} - L| < 5\epsilon$ whenever $n > N_{1}$. It follows now that $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n} = L$.

Comment: if I make it as n+1 > N , then n > N-1 , it will cange it to false statement?

Comment: It remains true in this case too, because then you are able to find an integer $N_{2} = N - 1$ such that $n > N_{2}$ implies $|a_{n} - L| < 5\epsilon$.

Comment: Remember that in the definition of limit, you should be able to choose a positive integer $N$ corresponding to an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $n > N$ implies the desired limit inequality.

Comment: How do you make this statement flse ?

Comment: I am surprised why do you want to make it false? Does your textbook ask you to make it false?

Comment: nah lol just curious